# if continuous function $f$ is zero almost everywhere then $f = 0$ everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

If the function $f:G \to \mathbb{R}$ with $G$ a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$,and $f$ is continuous.

Prove if $f = 0$ almost everywhere(In Lebesgue measure) then $f = 0$ everywhere.

My attempt: w.l.o.g assume $f(x)>0$ for some $x$,since $f$ is continuous ,there exist a neighborhood of $x$ with all $f(y)>0$ on the neighborhood,and the neighborhood is not measure zero.So we have the result.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. Congratulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct.

You can make it even more precise (but maybe cumbersome) using a $\delta$-$\epsilon$ argument. Since $f$ is continuous at $x$, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $||x-y||<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$. Since $f(x)>0$, say $f(x)=l$, we can take $\varepsilon=\frac{l}{2}$ and so $f(y)>\varepsilon>0$. This is true for all $y\in B(x,\delta)$ -the open ball of center $x$ and radius $\delta$-, whose measure is positive (you can even look at the [volume of the ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball) if you want to check that). So we have the contradiction.

Comment: Just a nitpick, $G$ is a domain in $n$-dim Euclidean space, but the procedure is the same.

Comment: Yes, I missed that. I'm going to correct it, because the only difference is changing absolute value by norm and the interval by a ball.